# Laplacian positional encoding in a pytorch batch

Tags: python, numpy, graph, pytorch

I am trying to recode the laplacian positional encoding for a graph model in pytorch. A valid encoding in numpy can be found at https://docs.dgl.ai/en/0.9.x/_modules/dgl/transforms/functional.html#laplacian_pe .

I think I have managed to make an equivalent encoding to numpy in pytorch, but for performance issues I would like that function to be able to work with batches of data.

That is, the following function works with the parameters
with the form `adj[N, N]`, `degrees[N, N]` and `topk` as an integer, where `N` is the number of nodes in the network.

```
def _laplacian_positional_encoding_th(self, adj, degrees, topk):
    number_of_nodes = adj.shape[-1].
    #degrees = th.clip(degrees, 0, 1) # not multigraph
    assert topk < number_of_nodes
    
    # Laplacian
    D = th.diag(degrees**-0.5)
    B = D * adj * D
    L = th.eye(number_of_nodes).to(B.device) * B

    # Eigenvectors
    EigVal, EigVec = th.linalg.eig(L)
    idx = th.argsort(th.real(EigVal)) # increasing order
    EigVal, EigVec = th.real(EigVal[idx]), th.real(EigVec[:,idx])

    # Only select [1,topk+1] EigenVectors as L is symmetric (Spectral decomposition)
    out = EigVec[:,1:topk+1]
    return out
```

However, when I try to perform the same efficient operations in batch form, I cannot code it. That is, the idea is that the parameters can come in the form `adj[B, N, N]`, `degrees[B, N, N]` and topk as integer, `B` being the number of data in the batch.

Comment: Are you sure about `B = D * adj * D`? you are using _element-wise_ multiplication (`*`). Shouldn't you be using matrix multiplication (`@`) instead?

Comment: @Shai That's right, I hadn't realized that. Actually I went on to do a recoding of the source I provide directly without making much difference, but it is true that D is a matrix so I will look in the original paper the implications of this and check numerically the outputs. Thanks for the note.

Comment: I also thing `degrees` is of shape `N` only (or `[B, N]`) - that is the degree of each node. There is no meaning for the degree of an edge?

Comment: Also what is the meaning of `L = I * B`? it seems like you are selecting the diagonal? This does not make much sense. Is it possible the issue here is not about making this code "batched" but making sense of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```py
def _laplacian_positional_encoding_th(self, adj, degrees, topk):
        number_of_nodes = adj.shape[-1]
        assert topk < number_of_nodes

        D = th.clip(degrees, 0, 1) # not multigraph
        B = D @ adj @ D
        L = th.eye(number_of_nodes).to(B.device)[None, ...] - B 

        # Eigenvectors
        EigVal, EigVec = th.linalg.eig(L)
        idx = th.argsort(th.real(EigVal)) # increasing order

        out = th.real(th.gather(EigVec, dim=-1, index=idx[..., None]))
        return out
```

See [`th.diag_embed`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.diag_embed.html) for creating a batch of diagonal matrices, and [`th.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) for selecting the right columns of `EigVec` according to the sorted indices.

**Updata:**
If you want to extract the `topk` vectors:

```py
_, topk = th.topk(EigVal.real, k=5)  # get the top 5
out = th.gather(EigVec.real, dim=-1, index=topk[:, None, :].expand(-1, EigVec.shape[1], -1))
```

Comment: I realized that that output returns only a value for the out, and I want the topk components of the eigenvectors for every matrix of the batch (for the spectral decomposition I'm looking for) so I think that idx vector should be repeated along the right dimension and then truncate those matrixes with the topk value. Is it possible to do with the gather function?

Comment: @Angelo please see my edit. To get vectors instead of numbers from `gather` one needs to `expand` the index tensor.